# How would I say "okay" or "fine"? (specific context)

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm aware you can say "d'accord" or "bien", but American English has things like:

> Fine! Mom!

or

> Okay! I admit it.

I don't think "d'accord" or "bien" seem to fit in those contexts, but I'm not sure honestly, I'm just wondering if there is a word that fits in that context.

Answer (score 3):

The "okay/fine"s in French do come in all flavours, just like they do in English.

In a spat between mother and daughter, you can say, for instance:

> Mère: Je veux que tu quittes immédiatement cette maison !
>
> Fille: **Très bien !** {= **Fine!**} De toute façon, j’avais prévu de partir !

As for "**Okay**, I admit it":

> **Bon**, je (te) l'avoue. Ça m'a coûté de rompre avec Camille.

Comment: On peut utiliser même Ok en français, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris  En fonction du contexte, oui. Pour ma part, je préférerais quand même utiliser d'autres mots  qui sonnent plus *français*.

Comment: @Dimitris Les francophones utilisent certainement beaucoup OK, du moins tous ceux que je connais. Néanmoins, je note que la traduction française du roman *The Road*, qui doit bien utiliser deux ou trois cents fois le terme, propose systématiquement *D’accord* en ces endroits. Une volonté de faire reculer l'usage? Une incapacité à intégrer ce terme maintenant commun à la langue littéraire? Je ne sais pas.

Comment: @Montéedelait Je plussoie. *Ok* est plus utilisé à l'oral que *d'accord*. Il est aussi courant à l'écrit dans les entreprises avec comme contraire *ko*, ce qui laisse perplexe les anglophones.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good answers, there is a rather recent use in spoken French, among teenagers (and at least in "European French", I could not say about "Canadian French"): *c'est bon !* as an expression of being fed up or upset by one's comments. That could match your example of "Fine, mom !" in some contexts.

> Range ta chambre, je te l'ai déjà demandé trois fois
>
> C'est bon, maman !
>
> Tu as des devoirs pour l'école ? Travaille bien !
>
> C'est bon, maman !

Answer (score 0):

**I** For "Fine! Mom!" the following option is available; it is given by DeepL translator but it it is rarely used.

**(Très) bien ! Maman !**

For instance, when a mother is asking her son to perform a little task he can answer that way, but more often he'll say omething else: "Mom" is not used much in answering questions or demands;

- **D'accord! (je le fais!)**
- **Oui! (je le fais!)**
- **Oui! (je vais le faire!)**
- (as well) **Ça va, je le fais!**
  …

**II** For "Okay! I admit it!" there are  several choices that I can think of.

**Bon! oui! je l'admets!** That is used after some insistence from the interlocutor for you to admit something that you've somewhat grudgingly denied or that you overlooked admitting for instance; it can be used in other such similar contexts with attitudes showing various intensities of irritation, sometimes because it means giving up on a given stance.

Instead of using the two words just one can be used; this is also idiomatic, but usually the speaker doesn't show to his interlocutor feelings as intense as when he uses the two together. This is more likely the form that'll be used when there are no hard feelings. Instead of using "bon" you can use "ben" but that is quite familiar.

**Eh bien, je l'admet!** This is a possibility that is used most often when the person speaks with a rather neutral atitude. Nevertheless, sometimes people will use this form vehemently, when they are in a real bind and think they have no solution, being so exasperated that, seeming to want to free themselves of an oppression, they drop their opposition as their resistance simply collapses. In this case of extreme behaviour "okay" will not do, I think.
 There  should be not confusion with the variant used when the speaker is angry because he did admit something and that the interlocutor is not taking it into account: "**Eh bien? Je l'admet!**"; the translation can't be "okay" then but rather "**well**" (Well? I admit it!).

**Eh bien, oui! je l'admet!** variant of the preceding

**Bien! Je l'admet!** variant of the preceding

**D'accord! Je l'admet!** This possibility is used in plain matter of fact circumstances.